# Xcode & Objective-C: Can't display Bold on a custom font from a ZIP file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, fonts, bold

In this app we unzip a file which contains a Fonts folder. Inside that folder we have some custom font in ttf format. 
We then display this custom font in labels and buttons and it works properly except that for BOLD.
Indeed, the bold get replaced by a standard font.

This is the code to load font:

```
- (UIFont*)loadFont:(NSString *)withName :(int)systemIndex :(CGFloat)size :(UIFont*) dftFont
{

    if ([self isAppleFont:withName]) {
         return [UIFont fontWithName:withName size:size];
    }


    if ([fontsDictionary objectForKey:withName]) {
        return [fontsDictionary objectForKey:withName];
    }

     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.ttf", withName];
     NSString* fontsFolderPath = [SystemsManager fontsFolderForSystemIndex:systemIndex];
     NSString* completeFontName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", fontsFolderPath,myString];

     if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fontsFolderPath] && [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:completeFontName]) {

         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:completeFontName];
         CFErrorRef error;
         CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
         CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);

         if(!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)){
             CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
             NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
         }

         CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(font, size, NULL, NULL);
         //CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont(font, 0, NULL, NULL);
         UIFont *uiFont = CFBridgingRelease(ctFont);

         [fontsDictionary setObject:uiFont forKey:withName];

         return uiFont;
     } else {
          return dftFont;
     }
```

And finally the code that set the BOLD.

```
-(void)setLabel:(NSString*)bold :(NSString*)italic :(UILabel*)label :(CGFloat*)withSize {

    BOOL isBold = ![bold isEqualToString:@"REGULAR"];
    BOOL isItalic = ![italic isEqualToString:@"NonItalic"];

    UIFontDescriptor * fontBold = [label.font.fontDescriptor
    fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];

    UIFontDescriptor * fontItalic = [label.font.fontDescriptor
    fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits: UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];

    UIFontDescriptor * fontBoldItalic = [label.font.fontDescriptor
    fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold
                    | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];


   if ( isBold && isItalic )
    {
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontBoldItalic size:0];

    }
    if (isBold && !isItalic )
    {
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontBold size:0];
    }
     if (isItalic)
    {
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontItalic size:0];
    }

    label.font = [label.font fontWithSize:*withSize];

}
```

Did I make something wrong or maybe is not possibile to display BOLD for custom fonts?

Best regards.

Comment: Too complicated code. Why you need manually load font's? Why not just register them in plist? Why you use font descriptor? Just get fonts with `fontWithName:`

Comment: @Cy-4AH it's a complicated app. Just know that we need to loads in the way I specified above. In the Fonts folder we have for example "Angelina.ttf" and we are trying to make that bold when it needed. How we know when it needed? From an XML file contained in the same ZIP.

Comment: I think you just need put in xml file complete font names instead of flags

Comment: @Cy-4AH The issue seems to be that we miss "Angelina-Bold". If we had it manually it still does not work.

Comment: @Lifetronic - ignoring your `setLabel:` method for the moment... What `.ttf` files are in your fonts folder? When you call `loadFont:` to load the "bold" version, do you get a valid new bold font? If not, step through `loadFont:` and see where it's failing.

Comment: @Cy-4AH I could solve the issue. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue with by putting a Bold version of the custom font into the Fonts folder and loading it when necessary.

So if you need a bold for a custom font in iOS you have to get a separate bold version of that font to make it works.